# How to skip Beanshell PostProcessor ( based on the regular expression output from previous http request ) by adding if controller

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 3.2 and I have a beanshell Postprocessor where it adds a number to the out from the regular expression (from previous HTTP request) `${FollowupBDays}`. Here is a snippet of the post-processor:

```
int FollowupBDays1 = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("FollowupBDays"))+4;
```

basically the regular expression `${FollowupBDays}` returns an integer value Ex: `3`, and in the BeanShell post-processor I am adding a number to the regular expression output i.e., `3+4` using the above line from the post-processor. I would like to skip the BeanShell Post-Processor if the regular expression returns null value i.e., if the output from regular expression returns the value `&nbsp;` since post-processor returns an error while trying to add `&nbsp; + 4`

Could you let me know the condition I can add to the If controller to skip the BeanSshell Post-Processor when the regular expression `${FollowupBDays}` returns the output `&nbsp;`

I tried the following conditions by adding if controller to the BeanShell post-processor and the condition always skips the post-processor regardless the value returned by the regular expression i.e., when the value is `3` or `&nbsp;`:

```
'${FollowupBDays}' != '&nbsp;'

${__javaScript(vars.get("FollowupBDays") != '&nbsp;')}
```

Comment: Also the Beanshell PostProcessor seems to be skipped if I add the condition to the if controller as '${FollowupBDays}' == '3' when the regular expression ${FollowupBDays} returns a value 3 and I would like to run the Beanshell PostProcessor in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to set any controller, including If Controller, for post-processor.

However you should handle a situation when variable is not an integer in the code of your post-processor itself. Best way is to catch exception:

```
int FollowupBDays1 = -1;
try {
  FollowupBDays1 = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("FollowupBDays"))+4;
} catch(NumberFormatException e) { /* remains -1 */ }
```

Alternatively, you can check for condition you were trying to use in If controller, before assigning the variable:

```
String FollowupBDaysAsString = vars.get("FollowupBDays");
if(!"&nbsp;".equals(FollowupBDaysAsString))
{
    int FollowupBDays1 = Integer.parseInt(FollowupBDaysAsString)+4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Kiril. I am able to skip the beanshell postprocessor using the the catch exception when the reg expression returns the value '& nbsp;'